# Snakemake only re-runs jobs if one of the input files is newer than one of the output files or one of the input files will be updated by another job

Tags: snakemake

I'm new for the snakemake. When I read the Snakemake Tutorial in Docks of snakemake, [the last sentence in step one](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/basics.html), I can't understand what the meaning. Could someone explain that, thanks a lot!

> Snakemake only re-runs jobs if one of the input files is newer than one of the output files or one of the input files will be updated by another job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that when you run Snakemake, it will look for the result files defined in the workflow (here it's `mapped_reads/A.bam`). If the files exist already, Snakemake will not run the workflow. But it also checks the timestamps of the files involved. If you change the input file, it might also change the output. So if Snakemake sees the input is newer than the output, it will rerun the workflow.